# Difference in asymptotic time of two variants of flatten

Tags: scala

I am going through the Scala by Example document and I am having trouble with exercise 9.4.2.  Here is the text:

> *Exercise 9.4.2* Consider the problem of writing a function `flatten`, which takes a list of element lists as arguments. The result of `flatten` should be the concatenation of all element lists into a single list. Here is an implementation of this method in terms of `:\`.
>
> ```
> def flatten[A](xs: List[List[A]]): List[A] =
>   (xs :\ (Nil: List[A])) {(x, xs) => x ::: xs}
> ```
>
> Consider replacing the body of flatten by
>
> ```
> ((Nil: List[A]) /: xs) ((xs, x) => xs ::: x)
> ```
>
> What would be the difference in asymptotic complexity between the two versions of flatten?
>
> In fact flatten is predefined together with a set of other userful function in an object 
>   called List in the standatd Scala library. It can be accessed from user program by calling List.flatten. Note that flatten is not a method of class List – it would not make sense there, since it applies only to lists of lists, not to all lists in general.

I do not see how the asymptotic time of these two function variants are different.  I'm sure it's because I am missing something fundamental about the meaning of fold left and fold right.

Here is a pdf of the document I am describing:
http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaByExample.pdf

I am generally finding this an excellent introduction into Scala.

Comment: Hint: given small and large lists (`small` and `large`), think about the cost of constructing `small ::: large` compared to `large ::: small`. Keep in mind the structure of lists as "cons" cells `hd :: tl`.

Comment: Right...concatenation is implemented so that x:::y traverses the entire list of x.  It's kind of an unfortunate implementation of ::: and I hope that ::: is not really implemented this way.  This would mean that the second implementation, using fold left, has an O(n^2) complexity, whereas the fold right implementation has a complexity of O(n) (will visit all elements twice).

Comment: Thanks for giving me a hint without showing me the answer.  This is what I had wanted...I should have been more clear in my question.

Comment: I agree, the best way to learn is to discover things for yourself. I was hoping you'd solve it fast enough to write your own answer :-) By the way, given the structure of lists as immutable cons cells, there's really no better way to write `:::` than rebuilding the left  list entirely. If you want a more sophisticated immutable data structure there's `Vector` which allows both append and prepend in near constant time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the implementation of concatenation `:::` (p.68) (the rest of answer is [masked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/add-markdown-support-for-hidden-until-you-click-text-aka-spoilers) with spoiler-tags, mouse-over to read !)

> Witness that it's linear (in `::`) in the size of the left argument (the list that ends up being the prefix of the result).
>
>   Assume (for the sake of the complexity analysis) that your list of lists contains `n` equal-sized small lists of size a fixed constant `k`, `k<n`. If you use `foldLeft`, you compute:
>
>  `f (... (f (f a b1) b2) ...) bn`
>
>  Where `f` is the concatenation. If you use `foldRight`:
>
>   `f a1 (f a2 (... (f an b) ...))`
>
>  With again `f` standing for the prefix notation of concatenation. In the second case it's easy : you add `k` elements at the head each time, so you do (`k*n` cons).
>
>  For the first case (`foldLeft`), in the first concatenation, the list `(f a b1)` is of size k. You add it on the second round to b2 to form `(f (f a b1) b2)` of size 2k ... You do (`k+(k+k)+(3k)+... = k*sum_{i=1}^n(i) = k*n(n+1)/2` cons).

(Followup question : is this the only parameter that should be taken into account while thinking of the efficiency of that function ? Doesn't `foldLeft` have an advantage -not asymptotic complexity- that `foldRight` doesn't ?)

Comment: Very nicely explained.  As I described above, I wasn't really looking for a complete answer, just a way to help me think about it.  But you have described it quite nicely and formally.  I'll have to think a bit more about how to get the extra credit, though...